# How to synchronize graphics card FPS with movie FPS automatically?

Tags: video, graphics-card, sync, hdmi, lag

When I watch movies on my PC I have to "guess" the movie's FPS (24, 25, 30, ...) every time, then set the guessed FPS in my video driver's `Refresh Rate` setting. Only then the movie is shown fluently without micro lags.

My setup:

- Intel HD Graphics 4600
- Display: Philipps TV, connected per HDMI
- Windows 7

Is it normal, that you have synchronize the Refresh Rate with the movie FPS?

Is it possible to let this setting set automatically? Or: How can I watch movies fluently without always setting the Refresh Rate?

Comment: The movies are local or is the movie delivered using a video-streaming service like Netflix?

Comment: Mostly Amazon Prime streams, but also videos from network share.

Comment: I don't know how to get the FPS from Amazon Prime, but you can get the FPS from the network shared movies' metadata. You can do this by looking at the video files' properties.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 On Amazon I guess the FPS and set it in Refresh Rate until the video is fluent. My problem is that I have to do this manually.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? If so, then are you using the dedicated W10 app?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Windows 7, using web browser

Comment: My workstation is damaged. It will be a day before I can compose a detailed answer.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Are you able to post a detailed answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bought a new dedicated video card. Now it works well.